# display multiple elements (divs and img) on load in a random position with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I’ve just started learning how to code in JavaScript, for artistic purposes, and would be very grateful if someone could help me with a particular work. I have collected all the elements of a digital journal (and separated them in divs and imgs), and I want them all to be positioned on the screen randomly and simultaneously (on load). This is what I’ve achieved so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #image{
                position: absolute;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Init(){
                picture=document.getElementById("image");
                spaceH=screen.height - picture.height;
                spaceW=screen.width - picture.width;

                setInterval (mover, 0);
            }
            function mover(){
                picture.style.top=Math.round(Math.random()* spaceH) + "px";
                picture.style.left=Math.round(Math.random()* spaceW) + "px";
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="Init()">
        <img src="myImage" id="image">
    </body>
</html>
```

I can do it with only one image and can’t imagine how to do it with many of them (I mean I know I’d have to use an array but I’m unable to figure how by myself). Also happens that if I try to replace the img tag for a div, it doesn’t work. Could someone help please? I’m going nut with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
var pictures = [];

function Init(){
    pictures = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    setInterval (mover, 0);
}
function mover(){
    pictures.forEach(img => {
        var spaceH =screen.height - img.height;
        var spaceW =screen.width - img.width;
        img.style.top=Math.round(Math.random()* spaceH) + "px";
        img.style.left=Math.round(Math.random()* spaceW) + "px";
    });
}
</script>
```

```
<body onload="Init()">
    <img src="myImage">
    <img src="myImage">
</body>
```

Comment: 1. I would init each spaceH and spaceW outside the setInterval, in order to compute then once. Then integrates the parameters in mover function

Comment: 2. This works for img, not for div as the img.height will return undefined for div. Div will work with clientHeight attribute. Same principle for width

Comment: Of course there are better ways, I'd just tried to make it work with minimal changes from his example but nice tips!

Comment: Could you please mark as correct answer? Thank you!

Comment: Done! Sorry I didn’t know, it’s my first time here. Can I ask one last question? I have several images and divs, but the images keep displaying on the top of the divs so I barely get to see the divs. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Probably the position:absolute, try to remove it!

Comment: If i do so, the function that move them stop working.

Comment: Can you tell me if this is OK? I don't understand what's the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/L56gsqon/

Comment: it doesn’t. img keep positioning on top of the div. This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/jun0L5oh/

Comment: I mean on the top of the other divs, the ones with text